# Proper way to have two controllers talk to each other via service (Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two controllers:

- a "summary" controller that gives an overview, but also includes a list of files the user has uploaded.
- a "Detail" controller that gives information related to a specific item.

On the Detail view the user has a (newly created) feature of being able to reset the changes they have made.  Part of the changes to be reset is to delete all any files that were uploaded.  Because of this, I need for the detail controller to tell the summary controller to delete the files it has.

I know I need to use the service to coordinate the exchange, but I'm not sure how to do this in Angular2.  The workflow I'm imagining is thus:

1. user clicks button on detail view to reset the page.
2. detail controller informs service that the summary controller should delete the uploaded files it has.
3. Service notifies Summary controller to delete the files.
4. Summary controller receives notification and deletes the files as requested.

I've been digging into how to accomplish this in Angular, and so I'm somewhat familiar with using EventEmitter() (the use of which is discouraged), and using Observables.  However all the examples I've seen don't seem to be using the pattern in the way I would be attempting to use it.

My question:  What is the proper "angular" way to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been digging into how to accomplish this in Angular, and so I'm somewhat familiar with using EventEmitter() (the use of which is discouraged),

These patterns exist for a reason. I would just use an event emitter (although in a type safe wrapper) https://gist.github.com/basarat/46936dec14ad985bee24f54f3977cb2d

> (the use of which is discouraged)

Ideally the *service* owns the data you so don't have `controller1 -> service -> controller2` data flow and just `controller1/2 -> service` (mutation request) `service -> controller1/2` (read data) etc.

Comment: This is what I pretty much ended up doing.  I had to have cross-communication between two controllers, parent and child.  I used $emit to go one way, and $broadcast for the other.  It works fine, but I feel like it has a slightly bad smell.  I'm hoping there's a better way out there, but for not this works. Thanks!